# How to get the range of selected cells using VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to write an Excel Macro using VBA. The problem is, the cells processed in this macro are selected by user, so I can't predefine the range.

Here is my code:

```
Range(???).Select
Selection.FormulaR1C1 = StrConv(Selection.Text, 3)
```

How do I take the range of selected cells to fill in "???" in the code above?

n.b.: User can select any range they want, and they can use this macro more than once.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If the User has already **Select**'ed, then all you need is:

```
Selection.FormulaR1C1 = StrConv(Selection.Text, 3)
```

**EDIT#1**

Say the user has **Select**'ed cells **A1** thru **A10** and we want to put a simple formula in the cells:

```
Sub SomethingSimple()
    Selection.Formula = "=1+2"
End Sub
```

This will put **exactly** the same formula in each of the cells.
However,if we want to put an "adjustable" formula in the cells:

```
Sub SomethingMoreComplex()
    Selection.Formula = "=B1"
End Sub
```

After running *SomethingMoreComplex* cell **A1** will contain:

```
=B1
```

and cell **A2** will contain:

```
=B2
```

etc.  So the "adjustment" has already been applied!

Comment: Thanks, I've tried that before, and it only works if I select one cell only. If I select multiple cells, Excel will erase all the data in the cells. Do you have any idea why this happens?

Comment: I tried it. It doesn't work with StrConv(). But I've found the solution : use `For Each x In Selection` to apply it to every cell selected. Anyway, thanks for your help!